# Low latency callback in C++

Tags: c++, callback, std-function

I have an event driven application. I want to keep the event handler  (`EventHandler` class capable of many/all events) a common implementation - while allowing the `EventSource` be changeable (specifically - at compile time).

To couple the `EventHandler` with the `EventSource`, I will have to store an instance of *handler* within the `EventSource`. I tried to store  *handlers* of various forms:

- pointer to an interface of `EventHandler` (that has public handler methods defined in concrete `EventHandler`'s
- instance of `std::function` - this provided greatest flexibility

However, in both cases, the latency in calling the target method/lambda was quite high (on my test setup about 250ns) - and to worse, was inconsistent. May be due to virtual table and/or heap allocation and/or type erasure ???

In order to reduce this latency, I want to make use of templates.

The best I could come up with is:

```
template <typename EventHandler>
class EventSource1
{
    EventHandler*   mHandler;
public:
    typedef EventHandler    EventHandlerType;

    void AssignHandler (EventHandler* handler)
    {
        this->mHandler = handler;
    }

    void EventuallyDoCallback (int arbArg)
    {
        this->mHandler->CallbackFunction (arbArg);
    }
};

template <EventSourceType>
class EventSourceTraits
{
    typedef EventSourceType::EventHandlerType   EventHandlerType;
    static void AssignHandler (EventSourceType& source, EventHandlerType* handler)
    {
        source.AssignHandler(handler);
    }
};

class EventHandler
{
public:
    void CallbackFunction (int arg)
    {
        std::cout << "My callback called\n";
    }
};


int main ()
{
    EventSource1<EventHandler> source;                  /// as one can notice, EventSource's need not to know the event handler objects.
    EventHandler handler;

    EventSourceTraits<EventSource1>::AssignHandler (source, &handler);
}
```

This method impose a restriction that all my `EventSource`'s to be a template classes.

**Question is**: Is this best way to achieve consistent and low latency to callback? Can this code be improved to avoid the event source classes be completely independent of event handler objects' type ?

Comment: Have you tried out what the latency is if - just for diagnostic purpose - you call one well known event handler from one well known event source through a statically bound function? Just to find out if the latency is really induced by the call and no other effects apply (like, for example, objects to be instantiated, dispatcher code to evaluate, threads that lock each other out, or what ever)?

Comment: Try and measure a plain unadorned pointer to a regular non-member function first. Can't outperform that. If you find its performance acceptable, you have a fighting chance. A virtual call should have essentially the same performance as a function pointer though. Have you done any real profiling?

Comment: @StephanLechner, a well known member function of a well known object takes <30ns consistently. 
A virtual call takes approximately 60ns but stays consistent.
Either of this is acceptable (because they are consistent). I get similar behavior with above stated code with template. 


p.s. I have not done profiling of any kind.

Comment: Lately i realize, my test method had a problem. The thread I used to compute the latency was doing a File I/O before every iteration.

I am not sure how/why it should affect, but when the File IO was replaced with dummy data in memory, the results were consistent even with std::function.

Comment: Now that my problem of inconsistent latency seemed to have been resolved, I am wondering if the above stated code can be made better?

I am rather interested in avoiding interfaces & class hierarchies.

Comment: @rat6 If you want to improve working code you should better ask this question at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Beyond the review, the code suffers from design. I am curious to learn this way of using templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this best way to achieve consistent and low latency to callback?

As suggested in the comments to the question, I'd rather *try and measure* to know if that's really a problem and what's the best alternative for you.
There doesn't exist *the best way*, it mostly depends on the actual problem.

> can this code be improved to avoid the event source classes be completely independent of event handler objects' type ?

Maybe the following can be a good point from which to start to achieve that:

```
#include <iostream>

class EventSource1
{
    using invoke_t = void(*)(void *C, int value);

    template<typename T, void(T::*M)(int)>
    static void proto(void *C, int value) {
        (static_cast<T*>(C)->*M)(value);
    }

    invoke_t invoke;
    void *handler;

public:
    template<typename T, void(T::*M)(int) = &T::CallbackFunction>
    void AssignHandler (T* ref)
    {
        invoke = &proto<T, M>;
        handler = ref;
    }

    void EventuallyDoCallback (int arg)
    {
        invoke(handler, arg);
    }
};

class EventHandler
{
public:
    void CallbackFunction (int arg)
    {
        std::cout << "My callback called: " << arg << std::endl;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    EventSource1 source;
    EventHandler handler;

    source.AssignHandler(&handler);
    source.EventuallyDoCallback(42);
}
```

See it on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/owg8tmRpdwW39oEY).

Comment: For the low latency program I am writing, i was expecting a solution comparable with the latency of virtual function. 

Your solution with templates works great for me. Thank You !

Comment: @skypjack this should perform much better than std::function

Comment: @svoltron Well, it's not a drop-in replacement for a `std::function`, it has its pros and cons. Btw I've extensively used something similar in a project of mine, [`EnTT`](https://github.com/skypjack/entt) (see class `delegate`) and it worked  quite well all the times I've used it in a production environment.

Comment: @skypjack that project of yours looks really interesting indeed, I'll look more into it. I'm into performance, I've not measured it, but at first glance, it should behave better than std::function. How about the cons you were speaking about?

Comment: @svoltron ie it hasn't the flexibility of an `std::function`, you cannot attach it a data member, you cannot attach a _compatible function_ and you have to adhere strictly to the signature, and so on. Btw in a high performance environment these are things of which you don't care much and you're usually willing to sacrifice features for performance, so go for it. ;-)

Comment: @svoltron Thank you, you're welcome. Feel free to contact me if you want to discuss it further.